# A word for an object that doesn't fit in.

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a word that describes an object that doesn't fit in, preferably a word that also can be applied to describe a person as well.

For example with clothing, you talk about 'regular fit', what is the opposite of a fit for bodies with an unusual shape.

Or a word for an object that doesn't fit into a box. Not necessarily an oversized object.

Or a person that doesn't fit into set categories, someone who doesn't have a box to tick.

I am either looking for single words and expressions.

Comment: Your clothing example doesn't quite fit-in with the rest of the question. Those are called, I suppose, *odd sizes* in that case. "We stock regulars and odd sizes."

Comment: Thanks for your question.  Are you asking for three different words (which should be different questions) or are you asking for one work to fit all of these (which you already state as "fit")

Answer (score 3):

Simplest word I can come up with is "misfit". Though please note the discrepancies among the dictionaries that I will outline below.

> n
>   1. a person not suited in behaviour or attitude to a particular social environment
>   2. something that does not fit or fits badly
>  vb (intr)
>  to fail to fit or be fitted
>  [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misfit)
>
> noun
>  1 : something that fits badly
>  2 : a person who is poorly
>   adapted to a situation or environment
>  "social misfits"
>   [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misfit)

There's considerable variation among the dictionaries as to exactly what uses "misfit" can have. For example Collins English Dictionary lists it also as an intransitive verb, Merriam-Webster Dictionary doesn't. Oxford Living Dictionaries gives the meaning referring to a person, yet labels:

> Something that does not fit or that fits badly.

As archaic.

Although "misfit" is usually used to describe a person who doesn't fit in, or is outside the realm of conformity or normality of a certain group, in my opinion it can be used for non-person objects as well.

For your own reference, you can see the [Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/misfit), which has definitions from three dictionaries, some mention ill-fitting garments, the American Heritage Dictionary labels it as archaic, while the Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary doesn't.

Dictionary.com lists the following:

> noun
>   1.a person not suited in behaviour or attitude to a particular social environment
>   2.something that does not fit or fits badly 
> verb (intr)
>   3.to fail to fit or be fitted
>  [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/misfit?s=t)

Cambridge Dictionary only lists the person definition. As I said, there is some variation among the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

[**square-peg**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/square-peg) (Collins)

> or **square peg in a round hole**
>   *informal*
>   a person or thing that is a misfit, such as an employee in a job for which he or she is unsuited

*See also the idiom on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole):*

> "As they say, you can't fit a square peg in a round hole. If your boss is like that round hole and you are that square peg, you aren't going to fit in unless you re-shape your edges." -- Gini Graham Scott in *A Survival Guide for Working with Bad Bosses: Dealing with Bullies, Idiots, Back-stabbers, and Other Managers from Hell* (2005).

Answer (score 0):

**Outlier**

From [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/outlier)(emphasis mine):

> 1. (Geological Science) an outcrop of rocks that is entirely surrounded by older rocks
> 2. a person, thing, or part situated away from a main or related body
> 3. a person who lives away from his place of work, duty, etc
>
> **4. (Statistics) statistics a point in a sample widely separated from the main cluster of points in the sample.**

The fourth definition fits your third example: a person who doesn't fit into the defined categories is a statistical outlier. 
(Might be a bit formal for your usage).